# Ansible Error Syntax ,Ошибка в синтаксисе

Tags: linux, ansible, yaml

И так,пытаюсь выполнить:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но пишет на ошибку в синтаксисе:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Пробовал пробелы ставить и убирать,не могу разобраться

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 0):

открыл в notepad++ и поправил пробелы и синтаксис

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).